# Connect Macbook Air with external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport, resolution

I have a MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013) that uses an Intel HD Graphics 5000. I also plan to buy the [monitor](https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B079P3YSTK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) that is supposed to have connectors for DisplayPort and HDMI with a resolution of 2560x1440 Pixel.

I would like to make sure that I can make use of the monitor's resolution with my Macbook Air.

If this is possible what cable do I need for that ?

P.S.: The monitor comes with two cables, DP and HDMI, so my guess would be I'd need an adapter. Yet this does not answer the question of the desired resolution. If you need more specific information please comment/ask below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google showed me that [this MacBook](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP678?locale=en_US) supports:

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native
>   resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an
>   external display, both at millions of colors

So, yes it looks like the Macbook will support the full resolution of your monitor.

Comment: Thank you Steve for the answer. This helps in knowing that it is possible. However I have doubts about the right connection. So my question is/was which cable do I have to use in order to leverage 2560 x 1440 resolution of the monitor.

Comment: Mini displayport is the native connector, so find a monitor with a mini or regular displayport (with no adapters) would be best